# What does class mean in a script?

Tags: javascript

Just a simple question.

I am looking at some javascript code here:

```
<script class="brush: java" type="syntaxhighlighter">
... some content
</script>
```

What do the class, type attributes mean exactly in this script element?

I get when type is set to javascript or vbscript but I guess this a technique to set it to your own script?  yeah.

And then what does class mean?

Note:
I have thru some doc: http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/script/
and the O'Reilly Javascript book by Flanagan. Just want a very precise answer if that's possible. Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure that's Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: I was referring to the script element which wraps around some java code. Will update.

Comment: Are you trying to use the syntax highlighter plugin (http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The class attribute is not valid in HTML 4](http://w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_class.asp)

[In HTML5, the class attribute can be used on any HTML element (it will validate on any HTML element. **However, it is not necessarily useful)**](http://w3schools.com/html5/att_global_class.asp)

The [type attribute](http://w3schools.com/tags/att_script_type.asp) specifies the MIME type of a script. "syntaxhighlighter" is not in the [list of standard MIME types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html).

Is this sample from a working web page? What doctype is it using?